# Laravel eloquent DB::raw select with orderBy clause and DATE_FORMAT

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a function returning data to populate a Chartjs in my view. I have pre-formatted the dates using `DATE_FORMAT` so that the Chart shows months and years. Now my problem is that I can't put these dates in `ASC` or `DESC` order after the format has been applied, doing so sorts everything in ascending or Descending order by month regardless of the year. what I want is to order them by year, in other words I want to order them by oldest records to most recent records or vice-versa. Below is my code:

```
 public function saleschart()
    {
        Config::set('database.default',  session('key'));
        $result = Order::select(
            DB::raw('sum(total) as sums'),
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months")
        )   
            ->where('status','=',2)
            ->groupBy('months')
            ->get();
        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

Is there a way that I can add `orderBy('created_at','ASC')` before I format the dates on line `DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%M %Y') as months")`

Any assistance will be really appreciated

Comment: The format has no relation with the `order by` clause. What's wrong with `orderBy('created_at','ASC')`?

Comment: @Felippe the problem with ```orderBy('created_at','ASC')``` is that I can only apply it after the dates have already been formatted which results in incorrect ordering of dates as at this stage the dates are in the format ```Jan 2019 e.tc``` the problem here now is that the dates will be ordered alphabetically, not the way I want them. Hence I need to know if I can use ```order by``` before I format the dates

Comment: If the column type is `date` or `datetime`, then you will have no problem at all using `orderBy('created_at','ASC')`. If the column type is `varchar`, then you can use `orderBy(DB::raw("DATEFORMAT(...) ASC"))`

Comment: If the column type is `date` or `datetime`, then you will have no problem at all using `orderBy('created_at','ASC')`. If the column type is `varchar`, then you can use `orderBy(DB::raw("DATEFORMAT(...) ASC"))`